# http post with blackberry

Tags: http, blackberry, http-post, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to set up an http post in my Blackberry app. I have successfully implemented this in my corresponding Android app, so I know the server it working find. I have tried several different things, and I'm not really getting errors, its just the info on the server is not getting updated. I have looked at this post:
[Http POST in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184223/http-post-in-blackberry), and several others. I found them helpful, but they didn't ultimately solve my problem. Again, I don't get errors, but the server doesn't get updated. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
String url = "http://xxxx.com/ratings/add?;deviceside=true";
String postStr1 = "business_id=790";
String postStr2 = "&rating=4";

HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
encPostData.append("business_id", String.valueOf(790));
encPostData.append("rating", String.valueOf(4));
byte[] postData = encPostData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length));

OutputStream os = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
os.write(postData);
os.flush();
```

Anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: What message do you get if you call httpConnection.getResponseMessage()?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455891/j2me-app-not-sending-post-requests

Comment: I get: Moved Temporarily ...what does that mean?

Comment: @JamesBlack I checked out that posted, and changed the appropriate case, but it didn't help.

Comment: I just checked what the encPostData.toString() was, and it was business_id=790&rating=4 - not the whole url. Is that what it is supposed to be?

Comment: remove that deviceside = true.. it wont come here

Comment: I removed the deviceside=true, and now I get a no stack trace with a "failed to transmit" message.

Comment: Ok, so I removed the deviceside=true, AND changed simulators??? and the message was send with no errors, however, my server still didn't get it...

Comment: Solved it! The key was deviceside...Thanks @Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things were going on. First, my simulator was not connecting to the internet properly. Once that got straightened out, I removed the

```
deviceside=true
```

from my url, and it now works great. Thanks all!