# http post blackberry (null response)

Tags: blackberry, http-post

I have used this code mod from some url [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500760/http-post-with-blackberry) :

```
    HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(webservice_address,Connector.READ_WRITE);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    encPostData.append("category", String.valueOf(category));
    byte[] postData = encPostData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length));
    OutputStream os = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
    os.write(postData);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    return httpConnection.getResponseMessage();
```

But response is always the same, i obtain a "null all times , when i was expected to have a JSON object response , any idea?

P.S: I'm sure server sends data

P.S: I have tried with Connector.READ_WRITE with the same result.

P.S: **I'm doing it in the blackberry 9930 simulator**

Comment: You are not mention that what you want in the entire post? You said I obtain a "null" like a house; what's the mean for that?

Comment: It would be a response with a JSON object .

Comment: Did you put like this:     HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(webservice_address+";interface=wifi"); and check the wifi connection; try like this.

Comment: @alishaik786 I'm doing it in the simulator

Comment: come on this chat room:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this sample code:

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread 
{       
String url;
HttpConnection httpConnection;
InputStream inputStream;
String id="0";  
StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
public ConnectionThread(String url) 
{   
    this.url=url;       
}
public void run() 
{
    try
    {
        httpConnection=(HttpConnection)Connector.open("Giver Your URL"+";interface=wifi");
        URLEncodedPostData oPostData = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);

        oPostData.append("category",id);//Parameters list;  
        oPostData.append("categoryName","Categ1");

        System.out.println("================"+oPostData.toString());
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, oPostData.getContentType());
        byte [] postBytes = oPostData.getBytes();
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(postBytes.length));
        OutputStream strmOut = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
        strmOut.write(postBytes);
        strmOut.flush();
        strmOut.close();

        int response=httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(response==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            inputStream = httpConnection.openInputStream();
            int c;
            while((c=inputStream.read())!=-1)
            {
                stringBuffer.append((char)c);
            }
            callBack(stringBuffer.toString());

        }
        else
        {
            callBack("ERROR");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
            StartUp.exceptionHandling(e.getMessage());
        }           
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            if(httpConnection!=null)
            {
                httpConnection.close();
            }
            if(inputStream!=null)
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e2) 
        {}          
    }       
}
private void callBack(String response)
{
    if(response.equals("ERROR"))
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
        // Put an alert here that "URL Not found";
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(response);
            //do what you want;                                     
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // Put an alert here that "Data Not found";
        }
    }
}   
}
```

This is a sample code for **POST** the data;

Answer (score 1):

Cau u please add Connector.READ_WRITE in Connector.open

```
HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(webservice_address,Connector.READ_WRITE);
```

Comment: I've tried it also , but simulator doesn't return good response

Comment: I have checked your code. It's working fine. I think you have mentioned host as localhost. So emulator couldnt reach your web serveice. So pls change it as ip. and also check ur url is wokring in blackberry browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to avoid calling `os.close()` before reading the response?