# HTTP connection in Blackberry with username and password credentials?

Tags: blackberry

I designed an Application which uses a web view. My Application has to hit the client’s site when opened. So, I need to make an Http Connection which should take username & password for validating and to catch the response from the server and load the content using that response. I have been trying to do but unable to figure it out. Please help me in this issue. Please explain with some code.

This is what Im trying to make an Http connection but it is throwing **401** response code. I think the problem is, it is not taking the Credentials im entering in the encoder.

```java
HttpConnection httpConn=null;
DataInputStream dis=null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;

URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData(null, false);
encPostData.append("username", PasswordPopupScreen._response2);
encPostData.append("password", PasswordPopupScreen._response3);

try {
    httpConn=(HttpConnection)Connector.open("myclient's siteURL");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE,
                                HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH,
                                String.valueOf(encPostData.getBytes().length));
    dos=httpConn.openDataOutputStream();
    dos.write(encPostData.getBytes());
    if(httpConn.getResponseCode()==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        //Dialog.alert("Success");
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        // Dialog.alert("failed");
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

why the response is getting as **401**? It means as Unauthorized access but im authorized to view my client's site. As of my Knowledge the problem is, the request is not appending the Username and Password. Please provide me help to appedn the credentials with the request.My client's server takes **NTLM** authentication.

Comment: Im trying it on a 9800Simulator

Comment: will you show us , what you have tried ?

Comment: ya i pasted the code below,which im trying. please help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18971/discussion-between-user1735165-and-black-pearl)

Comment: This link helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969666/http-post-blackberry-null-response/8981963#8981963

Answer (score 0):

Hi Refer this KB article to access HTTP authorization..

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-basic-HTTP-authentication/ta-p/445920

You need to add these lines in Your HTTP request for Authentication.

```java
String login = "username:password";

//Close the connection.
s.close();

//Encode the login information in Base64 format.
byte[] encoded = Base64OutputStream.encode(login.getBytes(), 0, login.length(), 
                                           false, false);

//Open a new connection.
s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open("http://mysite.com/myProtectedFile.txt ");
httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;

//Add the authorized header.
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encoded));
```

Comment: This is not working. My server needs an NTLM authentication. Above code is getting a response as 200 even if the credentials are wrong.