# Integrating Post Web Services in Blackberry app

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am very new Blackberry App Development and facing a big problem in integrating Web Services in my Blackberry app. I have to use Post Web Services in the Application and don't find even a single tutorial which explains how to integrate the Web services in Blackberry. Please some one help in this regard. I executed the example give at this [link](http://www.simplified-tech.com/website/webapp.nsf/webpages/ArticlesBBWebServices). Internet Avaialble when I try to open link Browser but it is not connecting to Web Services through my App.

Comment: SEE THIS LINK MAY HELP YOU... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969666/http-post-blackberry-null-response/8981963#8981963

Comment: I am getting :- Sometimes App Error 104 Uncaught: NullPointerException and Some time EOFException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this -

```
try {
        httpURL="http://google.co.in/";

        if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
                && RadioInfo
                        .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
            httpURL += ";interface=wifi";
        }else  if (TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B) && TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B)) {
            System.out.println("BIS CONNECTION-------------------");
            // Holder.connectionInterface=";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
            httpURL += ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
        } 
        //Dialog.alert(httpURL);
        HttpConnection httpConn;
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(httpURL);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        DataOutputStream _outStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.openDataOutputStream());
        byte[] request_body = httpURL.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < request_body.length; i++) {
            _outStream.writeByte(request_body[i]);
        }
        DataInputStream _inputStream = new DataInputStream(
        httpConn.openInputStream());
        StringBuffer _responseMessage = new StringBuffer();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = _inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            _responseMessage.append((char) ch);
        }
        String res = (_responseMessage.toString());
        responce = res.trim();

        //Dialog.alert(responce);

        httpConn.close();


    }catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert("Error -"+e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `DataOutputStream _outStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.openDataOutputStream());`.  You can just use `DataOutputStream _outStream = httpConn.openDataOutputStream();`.

Comment: @Signare I have tried your code and I am getting java.io.InterruptedIOException:Local connection timed out after ~120000. By seeing the above error we can under it is unable to connect server but not understanding why its not connecting. The same url when opened using simulators browser works fine.

Comment: @Signare No, I am testing on Simulator and I have Internet Connectivity through LAN.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-java

Answer (score 2):

before posting please google with "Blackberry+httppost" you will get lots of links.
Also for you i suggest one link which is useful to beginners. It sounds good.

Also you have to study Connection extensions like "interface=wifi;deviceside=true" etc..

http://randywestergren.com/?p=191